# validate form and email with nested if

Tags: php

I want to validate an form with email. I don't know if my code is good.
I don't know to put all together to do something maybe with nested if.
I want to do this:
1)if  username , password or address is empty to give an echo for each one
  whether it is valid and other echo that is invalid 
2)When  email address is misspelled to give an echo and if it is correct another echo. 
3)If an email address is empty to give an echo and for false another echo
4)Same with user , password separately for each empty, 2 echo one for true another for false .
  Please help!

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>


<form action ="form_testare1.php" method = "POST">
User:<input type="text" name = "user" />
<br/>
password:<input type = "password" name = "password" />
<br/>
Email:<input type = "text" name = "email" />
<br/>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value ="submit"/>

</form>

<?php

$password = $_POST['password'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(isset($_POST['user']) && ($_POST['password']) && ($_POST['email']))
{
    echo "user , password and  email are set<br/>";
}
else
{

echo "user:$user password:$password or email:$email not set<br/>";

}

if(strlen($password)>0 && strlen($user)>0 && strlen($email)>0){



        echo "User: $user<br/>";
        echo "Password: $password<br/>";
        echo "Email: $email<br/>";

    }
        else
    {
    echo "user:$user password:$password or email:$email are empty<br/>";
    }


        if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                    {

                    echo "emailul is valid";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "emailul is not valid<br/>";
                    }





?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would put the validation responses above the form. Your first command should be `if ( isset($_POST) );`  if it is not set, it is a first display and  there is nothing to check.

Answer (score 1):

To be short you can names your inputs as `data[name]`,`data[email]`...
and check like this

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $key=>$value){ 
 if($key == 'email'){ 
  if(!empty($value) && preg_match("/^(.*)@(.*)\.(.*)$/",$value)){ 
   echo 'email is valid'; 
  }else{ 
   echo 'email is invalid'; 
  } 
 }else{ 
  echo !empty($value)?"$key is correct":"$key is incorrect"; 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before  you have to correct

```
 if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['email']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename like this?

```
<form action ="form_testare1.php" method = "POST">
User:<input type="text" name = data['user'] />
<br/>
password:<input type = "password" name = data['password'] />
<br/>
Email:<input type = "text" name = data['email'] />
<br/>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value ="submit"/>

</form>
```